# Cassandra - read during update consistency

Tags: cassandra, database-replication, distributed-system, cassandra-2.1, consensus

Suppose we have a situation where R + W > N where R is the read quorum level, W is the write quorum level and N is the replication factor. We can further assume that R = W = N/2 + 1.

Let us imagine the scenario where an update operation for a key is in progress and say Cassandra has committed the update to a single replica with time stamp t. Let us also assume that the other replicas have the key stored with a time stamp that is < t. If a read request for the object happens now while the update is in progress, there is a possibility that the read quorum includes the single replica where the update happened containing the key with time stamp t and it will return a value that is not yet committed (a possible future value - I say 'possible' because the update may actually fail) because t > time stamps from other replicas in the read quorum.

The question is - isnt the R + W > N configuration supposed to guarantee strong consistency? Additionally, how is this problem resolved?

Comment: How do say the update may actually fail? it again depends on your Write consistency and number of live nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You are right on your asumption.

Cassandra transaction are not atomic in the sense of [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) of RDBMS. Which means that if an update failed the state of Cassandra is not unchanged and you possibly can read the updated value. You can refer to [this page](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_transactions_c.html) to get further information about Cassandra and ACID properties.

What we know is that if consistency level is reached in both writing and reading with R + W > N then we receive the most recent write. In other words, if Cassandra is available enough then it is consistent. That idea come from the [CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).